# RTK-query fetch data every X minutes and add it to stored data

Tags: react-redux, rtk-query

I have a "live graph" with many data points.
I want to use `rtk-query` to fetch the data from time A to now and store it.

Then, every X minutes, I want to call the API again in order to fetch the data from the last time point to now.

Two questions:

1. How do I ignite the call every X minutes?
2. How do I add to the store and not totally invalidate it?

Comment: try [pooling](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/polling). But I don't recommend you to use pooling if your data changes very very fastly. Instead you can use websockets

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call API every X minute, you can implement it with [pooling interval](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/polling).

Also, the same could be implemented through socket.io pooling or with plain websocket connection. If you do not want to cache the data, you can simply create redux middleware for socket.io - [check my code](https://github.com/lukahukur/trading-app/blob/78efa15a0defeb358ff18ebb92e53fcee7b0bb0e/client/store/wssMiddleware.ts#L23). Or if it's necessary to cache websocket data, you can use RTK Query `onCacheEntryAdded` function -
[here is a link](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/streaming-updates).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
const { data: returnData, error, isLoading, isError } = useFSTQuery({}, {
    pollingInterval: 60000, // This is in milliseconds.
  });
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isError || isLoading) {
      console.log(Data);
    } else {
      setFstData((oldData) => [
        ...oldData,
        {
          id: oldData.length + 1,
          reads: (returnData.subData1),
          writes: (returnData.subData2),
        },
      ]);
    }
  }, [returnData, isLoading, isError]);
```

I prefer not appending the data into the store. Instead, I use the store data to append into my hooks data.